How to enable "add a field" option in looker studio
I am not able to add field in the looker studio please help me on how to enable that option. As mentioned in the below image how to enable that option

I am trying to create custom field in Looker studio but I don't see such option can you please let me know as an administrator how to enable that option so that I can create custom field
